# why the "function-try" is not work in C++?

Tags: c++

Today I saw function-try in cppreference. When I wanted to use a test code to verify, I found that it can't catch exceptions; is there a problem with the way I use it?

```
#include <iostream>

[[noreturn]]
void foo(const std::string& str)
#ifdef _DEBUG
try
#endif
{
    str[-1];
}
#ifdef _DEBUG
catch (const std::exception& e)
{
    std::cout << "Exception : " << e.what() << std::endl
              << "In function : " << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl
              << "With parameters : " << str << std::endl;
    throw;
}
#endif


int main(void)
{

    std::string str{ "heelo" };
    foo(str);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`str[-1]` will not throw. You can do `str.at(-1)` to throw an exception. If you do not use the results it might well be optimized away by the compiler. Do `volatile auto val = str.at(-1);`